# how to Flatten json null to empty string in golang

Tags: go, flatten

I am searching for go library or work around to flatten the **null** json value to empty string (**""**),
from

```
`{
    "foo": {
            "jim":null
    }
}`
```

to

```
map[foo.jim:""]
```

as of now its being ignored for my use case.
can anybody help me with this.

example code https://go.dev/play/p/9hnMEa6QA2O
you can see that i get the output

```
map[fee:bar]
```

but i want

```
map[foo.jim:"" fee:bar]
```

Comment: make(map[string]interface{})

Comment: Can you post a reproducible example for this? like a go playground link?

Comment: please refresh the page for code link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after going through the code,
had to check for **nil** instead of ignoring it in switch case.

```
default:
        if v == nil {
            flatMap[newKey] = ""
        } else {
            flatMap[newKey] = fmt.Sprintf("%v", v)
        }
```